# Import namespace so prefix is not used

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a library that is in a name space, somewhat like this:

```
namespace MyLib {
    export class MyClass {}
}
```

I then have another class that is not in the namespace that looks like this:

```
class Test extends MyLib.MyClass {}
```

Is there a way for me to access `MyClass` without having to prefix the namespace? Maybe something like this:

```
import MyLib;

class Test extends MyClass {}
```

### Edit

I found out that I can do this:

```
import MyClass = MyLib.MyClass;
```

Which is okay, but based on that is there anyway for me to import all classes in the namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

The namespacing convention is a C#-ism that [doesn't translate very well to JavaScript](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/76qk4f/typescript_modules_and_namespaces_should_i_be/). My suggestion would be to stop using it altogether because it'll cause more headaches than solve actual problems.

Instead, you should treat your modules themselves as namespace "things". You could do this:

```
// MyLib.ts
class MyClassA {}
class MyClassB {}
export {
    MyClassA,
    MyClassB,
};

// Your code
import { MyClassA, MyClassB } from "./MyLib.ts";
```

Or in separate files:

```
// MyClassA.ts
export class MyClassA {}

// MyClassB.ts
export class MyClassB {}

// MyLib.ts
import MyClassA from "./MyClassA";
import MyClassB from "./MyClassB";
export {
    MyClassA,
    MyClassB,
};

// Your code
import { MyClassA, MyClassB } from "./MyLib.ts";
```

You can't "import all names" though, not in the way you'd need in C# where things are just magically scoped. They need to be declared somehow. On your example code, there's no way to tell that `Test` comes from `MyLib` - indeed, even though you could make it work (through global variables, e.g. `window.Test = Test`), TypeScript wouldn't be happy about it as it wouldn't be able to find a definition for `Test`, you'd need to `declare var` it somewhere.